# TotalElements returns incorrect value for total datatable rows

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement a query which returns paged request/response.

```
@Repository
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public interface OfferingsRepository extends JpaRepository<Offerings, UUID>,
        CustomJpaSpecificationExecutor<Offerings> {
        .......
}
```

Make a request into table with 23 rows:

```
Page<Offerings> all = offeringsRepository .findAll(
                new Offerings(searchCriteria, relevance),
                PageRequest.of(0, 20));

        long count = all.getTotalElements();
```

Count should be 23 but I get 20. I can't understand why I get value 20. It should be 23. Do you know how I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a separate countQuery in your API. By default, you are getting the count of records returned by the findAll() method which is top 20.

Sample code for your interface:

```
@Query(name = "SELECT offr FROM Offerings offr", countQuery = "SELECT count(offr) FROM Offerings offr")
  Page<Offerings> findAll();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code is located under lib which I can't modify. Any other solution?

Comment: Is it possible somehow to extend `findAll()` to include `countQuery = "SELECT count(offr) FROM Offerings offr"` without adding the query because I have a complex Specification and Inner Join?

Comment: You probably have to duplicate the criteria to get the exact count. Unfortunately, you cannot extend it.

Comment: One more question. Can I use my custom build specification into the native query that you pasted above?

Comment: I never tried that. You should be able to use a countQuery with specification. It is a JPQL.

Comment: Can you give me a hand, please? I don't have a much experience here.

Comment: Sure, let's try something like this and see if it works. I am also curious - http://pastie.org/p/2A2YiXQdEJOQCTwBLTsQV1